# Magento 1.7 top menu - submenu link generator

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

could someone tell me where I can find the code which generates the sub menu links in topmenu.phtml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()` [link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php#L218).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @KateGregory - The class reference will always remain valid. The link is a matter of convenience.